# Plex Media Server Not Working

Tags: plex

I just installed the plex media server, and when I go to configure it, my web browser says that it can't connect to the address.

Comment: Can you ping the Server ? and can you add a screen shot of the error.

Comment: Are you connected to the same network as the plex server? Try connecting to it from the plex server (using localhost instead of the ip). Are you sure that plex is running? Try running `sudo service plexmediaserver start` Are you sure you're using the right address? Check the ip with: `ifconfig | awk '/inet addr/{print substr($2,6)}' | grep -v 127.0.0.1` Make sure you're connecting to `http://plexipgoeshere:32400/web` and not `http://plexipgoeshere/web`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your CPU meets the Plex minimum requirements. I had the same problem until I upgraded my CPU.